# Kafka: store custom data at Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Just suppose one node cluster. I use Apache Kafka. Apache Kafka requires Zookeeper instance, where it stores internal state.

*Is it a good idea to store my application configs at the same Zookeeper instance? Or I need another Zookeeper instance?*

Will situation change when my cluster get more nodes?

Comment: high load on zookeeper by application, can cause problems with kafka. So, depends on what are you going to do and can you afford the second zookeeper cluster.

Comment: @Natalia thank you. As I understand, by highload on Zookeeper users usually mean more than few thousands RPS. I suppose I won't face performance issue during next year.